# bash - Pipe output from ls to rsync

Tags: bash, terminal, pipe, rsync

I'm trying to use `rsync` to backup folders containing a certain word, using `ls`, `grep` and `rsync`. However `rsync` does not seem to accept output from `grep` as input. I've tried the following:

```
$ ls -d $PWD/** | grep March | rsync -av 'dst'
```

This does nothing really, even though using just `ls -d $PWD/** | grep March` produces exactly the list of folders I want to move.

```
$ ls -d $PWD/** | grep March | xargs -0 | rsync -av 'dst'
$ ls -d $PWD/** | grep March | xargs -0 echo | rsync -av 'dst'
$ ls -d $PWD/** | grep March | xargs -0 rsync -av 'dst'
```

Many(including `dst`, here I escape space with `\`) of the folders contains spaces I thought that might cause problems and found `xargs` might be of help, but still doesn't move anything.

I have tried the above with `sudo`, the `-avu`option for `rsync` and `-r` even though this i included in the `-a`option. I usually use the `--dry-run` option for `rsync` but I've also tried without. What am I doing wrong? 
Is it possible to pipe input to `rsync` like this?

I'm on OSX 10.13.3. GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)

Thank you.

Comment: @rkta thank you. What would a 'go to' alternative be?

Comment: You are not feeding null terminated data to `xargs -0`...

If you want to limit the amount of files given as parameters by `xargs`, you need to add the `-n` option... if `dst` is your destination, you need to put the source before it, for which you need to use `-I` on `xargs`...  (likely with `-n1`). Using `echo` with `xargs` is the easiest way to debug it...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the problematic `ls` and `grep`, what you want is likely:

```
ls -d "$PWD"/** | grep March | xargs -r -n1 -I'{}' rsync -av '{}' 'dst'
```

A better method is to use `--include-from`

One option is to let bash emulate a named pipe:

```
rsync -av0 --include-from=<(find . -path '*March*' -print0) "$PWD"/ /dst/
```

You can also pipe the find output instead:

```
find . -path '*March*' -print0| rsync -av0 --include-from=- "$PWD"/ /dst/
```

`-path` is used to find "March" anywhere in the filename. (similar to `grep`)

(rsync might have some parameters to do the filtering itself as well, like the `--include` and `--exclude` patterns)

Something like this (untested). See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76237)

```
rsync -av --include="*/" --include="*March*" --exclude="*" "$PWD"/ /dst/
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you for that extensive answer! Clears up the ways to do it, as well as answering the original question; piping from **`ls`**.

Comment: Note: The `-r` option to rsync in unnecessary if `-a` is used, as `-a` already includes `-r`. However, if instead of `--include-from` you use `--files-from`, you should explicitly specify it (`-ar`) to have the recursive behavior, because `--files-from` removes it from `-a`.

Comment: @Giuseppe The find will return all the filenames though... (there is no `-type` o limit it to only directories / files) (`find` does the recursion, `rsync` does not need to)

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest creating first your list of files to either include/exclude and then do something like:

```
rsync -avz --include-from=list.txt source/ destination/
```

of

```
rsync -avz --exclude-from=list.txt source/ destination/
```

To create your list you could use something like:

```
grep -r March /path > list.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! I considered trying to just write the output of `ls -d $PWD/** | grep March` to a file and then doing as you propose and it might end up being the way I'll do it. Though I think it has less 'overhead' and is more intuitive to me if it was possible to do something like ones I've tried. Btw thanks for putting the `-z` option on my radar, would you use that almost always? Or is it intended for big files?

Comment: @Morten The `-z` is more a habit but check this in case you want to achieve more speed and get some ideas (indeed they disable compression): https://gist.github.com/KartikTalwar/4393116

Comment: [why not use ls](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls),  grep is more reliable

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. Using `find` to replace `ls` and `grep` and piping directly to `rsync`.

I ended up with the following:

```
$ find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -name '*March*' -print0 | rsync -av0r --files-from=- ./ /dst/
```

Here `-print0` and `-0` 'null-terminates' the data as described by Gert van den Berg (I have to because of spaces). The `-r` seems redundant as it is included in `-a` but when using `--files-from` it has to be specified for `rsync` to sync recursively.

Thank you guys so much, really appreciate it.